# D3 runs too slow for specs on this machine and I am trying to figure out why

Tags: diablo-iii, performance

Here is my setup: This is an ASUS, just a basic cheap computer.

Processor   AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 220 Processor, 2800 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)

System Type x64-based PC

OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium

Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 4.00 GB

Adapter Description ATI Radeon 3000 Graphics

Adapter RAM 256.00 MB (268,435,456 bytes)

I also have a laptop which has 256MB of video card RAM, Win7, 3GB of physical RAM.

The laptop runs the game perfect. The desktop (ASUS) runs the game *awfully*.

How can I make the desktop run D3 smoother?

Comment: Isn't the 3000 series os integrated graphics card? It doesn't even come close to the [minimum system requirements](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-system-requirements). Even the ~$55 Radeon HD 5570 has 4 times the speed and power of that 3000 series graphics card.

Comment: ATI 3000 represents the family, which is the true model of your videocard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video processor is certainly the cause of the slow execution.  If it is on the supported list then it might be one of the cards affected by a driver issue and you may need to update your Catalyst version.

The affected cards seem to be ATI Radeon HD 2400, 2600, 2900, 3400, 3600 and 4500 graphics cards but my 4300 series card was affected but not listed.

The hotfix to Catalyst 14.2 is described [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4876967911) with another user taking a more radical approach [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5051975559).